# SQL Select rows where col1 or col2 equals variable

Tags: mysql

So I want to select rows from table where col1 or col2 equals to variable, but if there is already row selected where col1 equals to variable (variable X) and col2 is anything else (variable Y) then it won't select another row where col2 equals to variable X and col1 equals to that variable Y. Everything ordered by column TIME descending.

Let's say this is my table:

```
COL1    COL2    TIME    COL4
1       2       0       A
1       2       1       B
2       1       2       C
1       3       3       D
3       1       4       E
4       2       5       F
3       4       6       G
1       2       7       H
4       1       8       I
```

And let's say that variable X equals to 1, then I want to have these rows:

```
COL1    COL2    TIME    COL4
4       1       8       I
1       2       7       H
3       1       4       E
```

So it won't show me this row

```
COL1    COL2    TIME    COL4
2       1       2       C
```

because there is already a combination where col1/col2 is 2/1 or 1/2.

Sorry if I explained it in a bad way, but I can't think of better explanation.

Thank you guys.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? ie SQL Server

Comment: I am using WAMP, so SQL server

Comment: Er, the M in WAMP stands for MySQL, so not SQL server

Comment: What's your PRIMARY KEY?

Comment: I've got "id" as primary key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making a couple of key assumptions...

```
SELECT a.* 
  FROM my_table a 
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT MAX(time) time 
         FROM my_table 
        WHERE 1 IN (COL1,COL2) 
        GROUP 
           BY LEAST(col1,col2)
            , GREATEST(col1,col2)
     ) b 
    ON b.time = a.time;
```

Comment: Thanks, this works perfectly. I appended "order by time desc" at the end, but that was the easy part. Thanks

Comment: This solution assumes that time is PRIMARY. You may well need to adapt it if that's not the case - as indicated by comments above.

Comment: I have added id after using your query and it's working fine

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**: I posted this answer when it was thought that OP's database was SQL Server. But as it turns out, the database is MySQL.

---

I think this query should do it:

```
select t.col1, t.col2, t.time, t.col4
  from (select t.*,
               row_number() over (
                 partition by 
                   case when col1 < col2 then col1 else col2 end,
                   case when col1 < col2 then col2 else col1 end
                 order by time desc) as rn
          from tbl t
         where t.col1 = x or t.col2 = x) t
 where t.rn = 1
 order by t.time desc
```

The key part is defining the `row_number` `partition by` clause in such a way that `(1, 2)` is considered equivalent to `(2, 1)`, which is what the `case` statements do.  Once the partitioning works correctly, you just need to keep the first row of every "partition" (`where t.rn = 1`) to exclude duplicate rows.

Comment: Smart approach and good explanation. `row_number` with `partition by` is such a neat and useful function.

Comment: I got this error when I used your code
`#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(
                 partition by
                   case when col1 < col2 then c' at line 3`

Comment: Ha. I think the error is pretty clear. You are using a MySQL database, not SQL Server like you stated in the comments. The query I posted will not work on MySQL. That's why the database information is so important on these types of questions.

Comment: Oh, sorry, didn't realize it's not the same thing.